# Can I relocate an outdoor feral cat when I move?

Tags: cats, feral, house-moving

I am in a rental due to hurricane Mathew, and will be moving in Aug. I have a feral Mama and 2 kittens. I  trapped  mama, had her spayed and vaccinated, brought her back and released.

I trapped the kittens, which were approximately 10-12 weeks old. I also had them neutered/spayed and vaccinated but I'm keeping them in a bedroom. They are becoming more tame each day. I have them on a waiting list for a beautiful no kill shelter, Palmetto Animal League, in Okatie SC. I went to see it. I already have a housefull of dogs and cats.

My question is, should I take mama to my house, few blocks away, and release her? That way I could feed her. Will it be too much for her? Here at the rental, she calls me twice a day to feed her. She is a great hunter also. It will break my heart to leave her. She has never let me pet her. I'm sure she knows that I have her kids. Signed, just want to do the right thing!!!!!!!

Comment: This may be of service to you :) https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/10468/how-can-i-move-houses-with-a-friendly-feral-cat-i-care-for?rq=1